# Distribute && over a list

Tags: operators

I cannot find an operator "RO" so that given a list, say {a,b,c}, 
RO[&&,{a,b,c}] 
produces
a && b && c

Comment: This is kinda tricky, but to understand why, evaluate FullForm[a && b && c] and you'll see that it's not multiple And statements but just one long one.

Comment: If it were multiple operations, you'd use `Fold`.

Comment: BTW the typical way is `And @@ {a,b,c}`.

Comment: @Szabolcs code is the short form of `Apply[And, {a, b, c}]`